# Creating Object C Array

Tags: objective-c, arrays

I make an array size of n;

It is not created.

**UPDATED**

```
int p[n];

for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
   p[i] = 12;
}
NSLog(@"%i", p[5]);
```

[RESULT OF EMPTY ARRAY](http://s22.postimg.org/9rra6gxkh/Screen_Shot_2013_07_04_at_17_32_19.png)

But when I use NSLog of eg. 5th item - I can see it is 12, **HOW** ?

Comment: Should be `i = 0` and `i < n`; you're writing outside the boundaries of `p[]` when `i` is `n`.  Why not use `for` loop?

Comment: You are creating it and initializing every element to 9...

Comment: What makes you think it's not created?

Comment: Is this C or objective C? If C then it will not compile due to int p[n].

Comment: for or while - doesnt matter, I cant use eg. if(p[7]==9) **BUT** I can NSLog p[7]. **WHY** ???

Comment: @Bathsheba: It is perfectly valid in C.

Comment: Yes, *why* can't you use e.g. `if (p[7] == 9)`? Do you get errors? Please post them (complete and unedited) in that case, also please post a more complete example (an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)). And please don't try to post them as a comment, edit your question instead.

Comment: @Guillaume Algis; I'm afraid it isn't. int p[n]; fails: n must be a constant. Try compiling it.

Comment: UPDATED and posted the result log

Comment: @Bathsheba: Actually, I did, and it compiled just fine. There is just a warning being issued, when compiling with `--std=c89`; `variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]`.

Comment: See the link above of the result. Empty array but NSLog works?!

Comment: @Guillaume Algis; Wow, I didn't know you could do that these days. Time to upgrade my compiler ;-) +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`p`, as far as the debugger cares, is the name of your array, it doesn't know how long it is as such. So when you print `p` it tells you about the definition (`(int []) p = {}`), not the content.

You could do this direct in the debug console too:

```
Printing description of p:
(int []) p = {}
(lldb) p p
(int []) $0 = {}
(lldb) p p[1]
(int) $1 = 12
(lldb) p p[20]
(int) $2 = 12
(lldb) p p[21]
(int) $3 = 992998680
```

If you define your array as `int p[20];`, then the debugger will respect the length and print the full contents of the array for you.